Invalid input syntax for type bytea
I have a function which looks like this:
DECLARE
  cityjson_text bytea;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO cityjson_text json_agg(cityjson) FROM (
    SELECT
      json_build_object(
        'tileboundary', ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y, margin => 0.015625))::json,
        'groundgeometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(groundgeometry)::json,
        'location', ST_AsGeoJSON(location)::json,
        'bbox', ST_AsGeoJSON(g.bbox)::json,
        'cityJson', 
        CASE WHEN z > 14 THEN json_build_object( 'cityjsonFeature',cityjsonfeature,
                              'cityJsonMetadata',json_build_object( 'translate',m.translate::float[],
                                                                   'scale',m.scale,
                                                                   'epsg', m.epsg)
                            )
        ELSE null END
      ) AS cityjson
    FROM 
      cj_geometry g
    LEFT JOIN metadata m ON g.metadataid = m.metadataid
    WHERE 
      groundgeometry && ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y, margin => 0.015625)
    AND 
    -- only intesect if there is a geojson exclude present
      (geojson_input IS NULL OR NOT ST_Intersects(groundgeometry, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_input), 3857)))
  ) AS cityjson_query;
      -- RAISE NOTICE 'Resulting cityjson_text: %', geojson_input;

  RETURN cityjson_text;
END;

If I run it like this:
SELECT _a_get_cityjson(16,35205,21497)

it works as expected.
If I run it like this:
SELECT _a_get_cityjson(16,35206,21497 )

it does not and fails with this error message:
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function _a_get_cityjson(integer,integer,integer,text) line 6 at SQL statement 
SQL state: 22P02

Any idea what the problem could be?

EDIT: I think I have found the problem: sometimes it fails if the constructed json is bigger then ~1MB. (which almost never happens).
I have found a way to avoid the error by returning a text instead of bytea but it seems like it does eat up more space sending the data as string. Is there any way to up the size limit?

Are you sure?
when the problem of constructed json is bigger then ~1MB isn`t :
ERROR:  total size of jsonb array elements exceeds the maximum of 268435455 bytes?

There's no 1MB limit you're hitting. At some point you're just finding strange values, like something with one of the first 34 ascii characters, which bytea won't appreciate: see this demo and this one.

Use convert_to() to make sure your json value is safely encoded. Assigning the json right into your output bytea variable might sometimes work, but as you can see it won't accept some characters.
Here I'm building a large json by generating numbers and looking up what ASCII character they correspond to, using chr(n):
create or replace function bytea_from_json_with_convert_to(
    x int,y int) returns bytea language plpgsql as $f$ 
declare _out bytea; 
begin select into _out convert_to(jsonb_agg(j)::text,'UTF8') 
from (select json_build_object('a',chr(n::int))as j
      from generate_series(x,y)n
      cross join generate_series(1,1e2)m
     )_; 
return _out; 
end $f$;

create table test1 as select bytea_from_json_with_convert_to(35,55295)as val;
select pg_size_pretty(pg_column_size(val)::bigint) as value_size
     , pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('test1')::bigint) as table_size 
     , pg_column_size(val) as value_size_exact
     , pg_total_relation_size('test1') as table_size_exact
from test1;




value_size
table_size
value_size_exact
table_size_exact




21 MB
22 MB
22276911
23175168



Note that final json is first encoded with convert_to(), which I'm not doing in the function below, like you did:
create or replace function bytea_from_json_without_convert_to(
    x int,y int) returns bytea language plpgsql as $f$ 
declare _out bytea; 
begin select into _out jsonb_agg(j)
from (select json_build_object('a',chr(n::int))as j
      from generate_series(x,y)n
      cross join generate_series(1,1e2)m
     )_; 
return _out; 
end $f$;

create table test2 as select bytea_from_json_without_convert_to(35,55295)as val;
select pg_size_pretty(pg_column_size(val)::bigint) as value_size
     , pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('test2')::bigint) as table_size 
     , pg_column_size(val) as value_size_exact
     , pg_total_relation_size('test2') as table_size_exact
from test2;




value_size
table_size
value_size_exact
table_size_exact




21 MB
22 MB
22276811
23175168



The size difference is negligible and the one without convert_to() refuses to handle the characters 1-34:
select left(encode(bytea_from_json_with_convert_to(1,34),'escape'),50);




left




[{"a": "\u0001"}, {"a": "\u0001"}, {"a": "\u000



select left(encode(bytea_from_json_without_convert_to(1,34),'escape'),50);

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function bytea_from_json_without_convert_to(integer,integer) line 3 at SQL statement

